# How to handle async test in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha-phantomjs

I have an event handler function that takes some event data and a callback function as input.

This event handler is using a promise to do its job:

```
function myHandler(event, callback) {
  somePromise(event).then((result) => {
    if (result.Error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      callback(null, result.SuccessData);
    }
  });
}
```

I have the following code to test the handler:

```
it('test handler', function(done) {
  let event = {...};
  myHandler(event, function(error, success) {
    expect(success).to.not.be.null;
    expect(error).to.be.null;
    expect(success.member).to.be.equal('expected');
    done();
  }
});
```

When running this test, I receive this error:

```
(node:3508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): AssertionError: expected 'unexpected' to equal 'expected'
```

and a the end of all the tests:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

but yet the test is still passing...

Why is this error occuring while the `done()` function is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your test into a promise that rejects if the assertion fails.

```
it('test handler', () => {
  let event = {...}
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myHandler(event, (error, success) => {
      try {
        expect(success).to.not.be.null;
        expect(error).to.be.null;
        expect(success.member).to.be.equal('expected');
        resolve();
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Promises.
You can either return your Promise without using `done`, like this:

```js
// Note the absence of the done callback here
it('test handler', function() {
  let event = {...};
  return myHandler(event, function(error, success) {
    expect(success).to.not.be.null;
    expect(error).to.be.null;
    expect(success.member).to.be.equal('expected');
  }
});
```

Or use [Chai As Promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised):

```js
it('test handler', function(done) {
  let event = {...};
  myHandler(event, function(error, success) {
    expect(success).to.not.be.null;
    expect(error).to.be.null;
    expect(success.member).to.be.equal('expected');
  }.should.notify(done)
});
```

The later seems better to me, as if you forget the `return` in the first example, your tests can silently fail.

Comment: As `myHandler` is not a promise, returning is does not work unfortunately. I may give Chai As Promised a try but will it work if the tested method is not a promise?